# powershell auto login script not working

Tags: shell, internet-explorer, powershell, autologin

This is my url

```
https://webmail.fasttrackteam.com/Login.aspx
```

I am able to open this path in IE.
but unable to set loginid & password.
Also dont know how to fire click event.

following is code that I have tried.

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate("https://webmail.fasttrackteam.com/Login.aspx")
$ie.visible = $true


$doc = $ie.document
$user = $doc.getElementById("ctl00_MPH_txtUserName")
$password = $doc.getElementById("ctl00_MPH_txtPassword")
$submit = $doc.getElementById("ctl00_MPH_btnEnterClick")

$user.value = "emailid"
$password.value = "password"
$submit.Click();

$ie.Quit();

$ie.Document.body | Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\amol.kshirsagar\Documents\FastTrack\Work\Extra\AutoLogin\log.txt
```

EDIT

This is error that I am getting,

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the `Quit()` method before accessing the `Document.body` member. As the `Quit()` call, well, quits the application, don't you think it should be somewhat peculiar to access its data afterwards?

Try accessing the member first, then quitting the browser instance.